# Visual Studio express keyword for creating a collapsable code block

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I remember there was some word one could type, so that a code part could be collapsed.
However I've forgotten it.  What was it?

(It worked on the express edition)

Comment: To do that, you could use shortcut: Ctrl+M+M - for both opening and collapsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#region NameOfRegion

the code

#endregion
```

Comment: i choose this as the best answer, Drew Noakes and Limonana gave nice answers too, but i think you where first and like your sample #region is not realy specific to a function its rather used around blocks of code

Comment: How can I expand/collapse the region as soon as I've created it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about `#region` directives. Use them like this:

```
#region Properties

public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

[www.sambeauvois.be/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/VS2010CsharpKeyBinding2.png](http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/VS2010CsharpKeyBinding2.png)

The first hotkeys are relevant for  opening and collapsing.